# Define a function to normalize data in python Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a database Customer Telecom Churn.
I want to normalize 2 columns which are "Tenure" and "MonthlyCharges"
I created a function normalization in order to do so.

```
def normalization :
     return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
data['tenure']=normalization(data['tenure'])
```

However I get the following error

```
File "<ipython-input-52-3a1b500deade>", line 1
    def normal:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

Comment: To define a function you'll need parentheses after the function name and before the colon.  `def normalization():`

Answer (score 0):

```
def normalization(x):
     return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I forgot that